# Set label layout in panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

in my Frame, i'm adding labels thanks to a for, in a panel. the problem i can't solve is that it is adding the label on the same line whereas i want to add a \n between one and another so to generate a column! I've no idea how to do it. any help? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the relevant bits of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key I believe will be the layout of the container that is holding the JLabels. If you give that container the proper layout such as a BoxLayout oriented along the PAGE_AXIS, or a `GridLayout(0, 1)` for one column with variable number of rows, then the JLabels will stack one on top of the other.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StackingLabels extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] TEXTS = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };

    public StackingLabels() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (String text : TEXTS) {
            add(new JLabel(text));
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        StackingLabels mainPanel = new StackingLabels();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StackingLabels");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Another thought is to use a JList to display the Strings rather than stacked JLabels.